# How to create jenkins plugin with java11

Tags: maven, jenkins-plugins, java-11

I am creating jenkins plugin with java11 and maven project but receiving error:-

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M2:enforce (display-info) on project abcdef: Execution display-info of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M2:enforce failed: Unknown JDK version given. Should be something like "1.7", "8", "11", "12"

Followed steps mentioned in URL:- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Java+11+Developer+Guidelines

```
<parent>
 <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.42</version>
</parent>

<properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 <java.level>11</java.level>
</properties>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
  <artifactId>jenkins-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.173</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also followed above steps in jenkins hello world plugin and received same error. As per details mentioned in URL, jenkins is having support for java11 so expecting that .hpi file should create with java11.

Comment: You are using [org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:3.9](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.plugins/plugin?repo=jenkins-releases) which was released in April 2018. Therefore this plugin is older than Java 11 which makes me no wonder that it does not support Java 11. Use a new version like 3.42.

Comment: Yes correct. Updated question and error.